# CakePHP updateAll() issues

Tags: cakephp

I have an images table with a column called `type`. I simply want to update all the rows to change the type to `gallery` where the `user_id` matches a particular user.

I am using this code

```
    $this->Image->updateAll(array('Image.type' => 'gallery'), 
    array('Image.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id')));
```

But I get this error: `SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'gallery' in 'field list'`

Why is gallery being added to the field list ?
Isn't the syntax supposed to set type to gallery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Found this on [the manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions):

> The $fields array accepts SQL expressions. Literal values should be quoted manually.

Thus, the following should work:

```
$this->Image->updateAll(
    array('Image.type' => "'gallery'"), 
    array('Image.user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))
);
```

Comment: Damn, excellent answer, I've been staring at a similar query all morning.

Answer (score 1):

In your model do something like this in your method ....

```
public function saveImage($type='')
{
 // I would add a test for $type
 $db = $this->getDataSource();
 $fields = array('type' => $db->value($type, 'string')); // $db->value() will format strings needed for updateAll()
 $condition = array('user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'));

 // I would add a test for user id before running updateAll()

  $this->updateAll($fields, $conditions);
```

}