# updateAll stripping quotes from fields

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have this function in my controller...

```
public function updateMany() {
    $fields = $this->request->data['fields'];
    $conditions = $this->request->data['conditions'];
    if(!$this->request->is('post')) {
        throw new BadRequestException('Method must be POST.', 400);
    } else {
        if ($this->{$this->modelClass}->updateAll($fields, $conditions)) {
            $message = 'Saved, '. $this->{$this->modelClass}->getAffectedRows() .' rows affected.';
        } else {
            throw new BadRequestException('An error occurred while saving.', 500);
        }
    }
    $this->response->statusCode(200);
    $this->set(array(
            'message' => $message,
            '_serialize' => array('message')
    ));
}
```

I'm passing the following JSON:

```
{
  "fields": {"foo": "bar"},
  "conditions": {"foo": "baz"}
}
```

My response is:

```
{
    "code": 500,
    "name": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;bar&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;",
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column &#039;bar&#039; in &#039;field list&#039;",
    "url": "\/site\/foobars\/updateMany",
    "error": {
        "errorInfo": [
            "42S22",
            1054,
            "Unknown column 'bar' in 'field list'"
        ],
        "queryString": "UPDATE `website`.`foobars` AS `FooBar`  SET `FooBar`.`foo` = bar  WHERE `disguise` = 'baz'"
    }
}
```

The problem is:

```
SET `FooBar`.`foo` = bar
```

Should be:

```
SET `FooBar`.`foo` = 'bar'
```

The WHERE is working correctly... why are the quotes getting stripped from the SET in the `updateAll()` function?

`foo` structure: `varchar(50)   utf8_general_ci`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with cakephp, but is it this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6988292/2734189

Comment: Try with json_decode() before updateAll()

Comment: @SumanSingh, that gives me: `Warning (2): json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [APP\Controller\AjaxController.php, line 120]`

Comment: Panic/Fuzzy, that seems to work.... seems odd to have to do that... would be annoying to have to do it every time I need to send json data for updating... I'll have to create some utility or something I guess.

Comment: I just ended up doing this in the first line of `updateMany()`: `$fields = array_map(function($val) { return "'".$val."'"; }, $this->request->data['fields']);`